# Increasing depth of document

Tags: numbering, theorems, amsart

I am trying to type by using `amsart`. I want numbering of the definitions, lemma theorem etc should be of the form x.y.z, where x is section, y subsection and z the actual number of the theorem. I ave used `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}` but it does not seem to be working. (Moreover I do not want any table of contents). Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`secnumdepth` is something different; it determines which section headings should receive numbers, not the numbers that they receive.

When you define your `definitions`, `lemmas`, etc, you have the option to determine which counters they inherit; for example,

```
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[subsection]
```

will define the `definition` environment to use the `subsection` counter. Here's a complete MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[subsection]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[subsection]

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
\lipsum[1]  
\end{definition}
\begin{lemma}
\lipsum[1]  
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

Comment: While this is a correct answer to the question, I'd recommend *not* to number statements by subsection, which makes it impossible not to use subsections; moreover, the number will be very long: `<chapter>.<section>.<subsection>.<statement>`